# Alcohol to improve blood flow?

Tags: health, alcohol

I read an article saying alcohol improves blood flow but it does not mention which kind.

What do you think about this?

Comment: Have you done a Google search? There are many hits including: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5513687/

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's ethanol

Answer (score 3):

Alcohol relaxes your blood vessels as it is a [vasodilator](https://www.medicinenet.com/vasodilators_drug_class_side_effects_list_of_names/article.htm).

That means it can improve blood flow - although [the negatives far outweigh the positives](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/health-and-families/health-news/what-alcohol-really-does-to-your-body-5349097.html) and most people aren't required to take vasodilators and can be harmed by them.

This is also where the old wives tale about drinking whiskey if you're cold comes from ([think St Bernards](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/20908/why-are-st-bernards-always-depicted-barrels-around-their-necks)). It can save your fingers from frost bite, but your body is actually restricting the blood flow for good reason - you may loose fingers but you have a better chance of survival - so it's better to only have that whiskey once you're back in the warmth. Drinking will relax the capillaries in your fingers and toes, allowing the warm blood from your centre-of-mass to flow. This actually means the [overall temp of your body will cool down.](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/32256/does-drinking-alcohol-really-keep-you-warm-when-its-cold-out)

As to which kind is "best" it's simply the drink with the highest alcohol content.  Hence traditionally something such as Whiskey or Brandy. For added effect though, you could consider drinks with a high concentration of other naturally occurring vasodilators such as these (from first link):

- Coenzyme Q10
- L-arginine
- Magnesium
- Cocoa
- Garlic
- Niacin (nicotinic acid or vitamin B3)
- mint (which contains levomenthol)